# What is wrong with this solution of mine for the PKU Judge ID 1003?

Tags: c++

Here is the link to the Problem ID 1003 of the PKU Judge: http://poj.org/problem?id=1003

All we need to do for this problem is to calculate the sum of a Harmonic Progression and Compare it with the variable we have already inputted

I am getting right answers for the sample input cases, but I don't know why my answer is not getting accepted? I am getting 'Wrong Answer' as the Result.
The was a part in the problem that says "The input consists of one or more test cases, followed by a line containing the number 0.00 that signals the end of the input" I don't know how to do that 0.00 part, I am just taking single input, I didn't understand how to do that?

Here is my solution:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    float c;
    float sum = 0;
    cin >> c;

    short int i = 1;

    while(1)
    {
        sum += (float)1/(i+1);

        if(sum >= c)
        {
            cout << i << " card(s)";
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Debugger** is your friend (best friend).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about proof-reading program functionality instead of a specific programming issue.

Comment: It does not fullfill the problem. For example:"The input consists of one or more test cases, followed by a line containing the number 0.00 that signals the end of the input". You do not check for 0.00, nor do you save a list of inputs.

Comment: Also, you do not test if the input is formatted right: "Each test case is a single line containing a positive floating-point number c whose value is at least 0.01 and at most 5.20; c will contain exactly three digits."

Answer (score 1):

> The input consists of one or more test cases, followed by a line containing the number 0.00 that signals the end of the input. Each test case is a single line containing a positive floating-point number c whose value is at least 0.01 and at most 5.20; c will contain exactly three digits.

Your program won't take correct input.

Comment: So what will be the solution?? How to make that correction?

Comment: Process input in a loop, your program should work with multiple test cases

Answer (score 0):

1. **The input consists of one or more test cases.**
2. **Use the exact output format shown in the examples**, which means you should print a line break after each case.

I made a little changes to your code to get it accepted.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float c;
    while (true) {
        cin >> c;
        if (c == 0.0)
            return 0;
        float sum = 0;
        short int i = 1;
        while (1) {
            sum += 1.0 / (i + 1);
            if (sum >= c) {
                cout << i << " card(s)" << endl;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what is the reason that your code is working and mine was not, I tried putting an endl in my code but it stil

this is the new code I used:

>#include<iostream>
>
>using namespace std;
>
>int main()
>{
>   float c;
>   cin >> c;
    if(c == 0.00)
        {
           return 0;
        }

        float sum = 0;
        short int i = 1;

        while(1)
        {
            sum += (float)1/(i+1);

            if(sum >= c)
            {
                cout << i << " card(s)" << endl;
                break;
            }
          i++;
        }
       return 0;
    }

Comment: @user2533630: Both answers say the same thing. The input can contain __more than one test case__. How many test cases will your code accept?

Comment: @user2533630 As I said: **The input consists of one or more test cases.**